# PCI-Express 2.0 backwards compatibility?

Tags: graphics-card, compatibility

I have a [Radeon HD 6850](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0047ZGIUK) which is a PCI-E 2.0 card. Will it work with a [ASUS P5N-SLI](http://www.asus.com/Motherboards/Intel_Socket_775/P5NSLI/#specifications) which has only PCI-E input?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [Wikipedia article on PCI Express](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PCI_Express#PCI_Express_2.0):

> PCIe 2.0 motherboard slots are fully backward compatible with PCIe v1.x cards. PCIe 2.0 cards are also generally backward compatible with PCIe 1.x motherboards, using the available bandwidth of PCI Express 1.1. Overall, graphic cards or motherboards designed for v2.0 will work with the other being v1.1 or v1.0a.

Comment: @Synetech backward compatibility on both sides is by design, and is more common than you might suspect: PCIe, IDE, SATA, USB, etc. When this isn't the case, the connector is usually designed so an incompatible component can't physically plug in.