# How to upgrade my GPU to MSI NVIDIA N630GT-MD4GD3 4 GB DDR3 Graphic card?

Tags: graphics-card, motherboard

I want to know about my motherboard's PCI express version.

Details about my motherboard:

[image]

I have PCI express slot and I want to upgrade it to MSI NVIDIA N630GT-MD4GD3 4 GB DDR3 Graphic card.. this GPU has PCI exp version 2.

I was told that I have to check if the PCI express of my board is compatible to that GPU.

I mailed to my computer's manufacturer (Acer), but they didn't reply.

Any help?

Comment: possible duplicate of [PCI-Express 2.0 backwards compatibility?](http://superuser.com/questions/429235/pci-express-2-0-backwards-compatibility)

Answer (score -1):

According to the Manufacturer's website it appears your board supports PCI Express X16 in the Orange slot. But your manufacturer's says you support PCI Express Lite which is a label I have not seen before. Although looking at the picture provided by the manufacturer, it appears you have a full length PCI-Ex channel, but I can't find any indication that your board supports PCI Ex 2.0. Even without 2.0, you can still run the card, as 2.0 and 1.0 is generally backwards compatible on both cards and boards, although some users have reported issues.

References:
http://www.ecs.com.tw/ECSWebSite/Product/Product_Detail.aspx?DetailID=817&MenuID=16&LanID=0
http://www.msi.com/product/vga/N630GT-MD4GD3.html#/?div=Specification

Comment: yes i have this 1 mainboard same hardware....

Comment: so can i but this gpu ??

Comment: so can i buy* this gpu ??

Comment: You should be good to go.